ASP.NET application, Converting login to use FusionAuth, Login Button needs to fire 2 times before redirecting to AuthLogin
I'm working on a website that currently uses a membership driven login, but they are wanting us to switch to using a FusionAuth login, before trying to use this login we have to verify the customers data set is ready for FusionAuth, I've gotten this process down and we have tied in middleware to handle the authentication.
On the main login screen I search for and validate if they are setup after they select their data set for login(getting our application and tenant id's for each data set), I also have an asp:LinkButton that replaces the current login button when we hide the old login name/password fields.
Now the problem I'm having is: I have to click the link button 2 times for it to actually redirect to the FusionAuth endpoint.
The following is my click event handler for the LinkButton:
public void FusionAuthLogin(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     // Get the customer number
     string custNumber = TextboxCustomer.Text.Trim();

     // Get the customer database
     string custDatabase = "Starter_Database";

     if (ddlDatabase.SelectedIndex != -1) 
     {
         custDatabase = ddlDatabase.SelectedItem.Value.Trim();
     }

     // Get the matching FusionAuth application's ClientId
     string fusionAuthClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId:" + custDatabase];

     // Add the customer number and database as state values to the auth request
     var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
     authProps.Dictionary.Add(FusionAuthMiddlewareHelper.CustomerNumberStateName, custNumber);
     authProps.Dictionary.Add(FusionAuthMiddlewareHelper.CustomerDatabaseStateName, custDatabase);

     // Authenticate with FusionAuth
     HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authProps, FusionAuthMiddlewareHelper.AuthenticationType + "_" + fusionAuthClientId);

     // The above auth challenge should redirect to FusionAuth
     // In case it does not, an error can be displayed

     return;
}

I have put a break point in the code, and it runs both time I click the button, but the first time appears to reload the page and after filling back in the database information it runs fine the second time.
I have also tried moving the link button outside of the updatepanel and i get the same results, i have to click the button 2 times for it to redirect properly.
The over all control is in an updatepanel, with the linkbutton having a postbacktrigger
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel>
            <table>
                ...
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButtonFusionAuthLogin" runat="server" 
                             CausesValidation="false" Height="100%" CssClass="Button"  
                             OnClick="FusionAuthLogin" type ="button" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Log In&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ....
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID ="linkButtonFusionAuthLogin" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


When you debug it, the first click, does it just skip over the Authenticate with FusionAuth liine? What exactly happens when you step through the first click?

on the first click it runs the code fully, but changes the url to http://localhost/MySite/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FMySite%2FLogin.aspx from http://localhost/MySite/Login.aspx, and page_load is fired off again.
On second click it reroutes to the FusionAuth then returns back to the login page where i authenicate the token and move on to the rest of the site like it should
